# Scale measurement data

Tags: gnuplot, scaling

I have some measured data, `experiment.dat` which goes like this:

```
1 2
2 3
```

Now I want to plot them via some command line

```
plot "experiment.dat" using 1:2 title "experiment" with lines lw 3
```

Is there some way how to scale the different lines with some scaling factor like -1?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do any kind of calculations inside the `using` statement. To scale the `y`-value (the second column) with `-1`, use

```
plot "experiment.dat" using 1:(-1*$2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to multiply the column by minus one, you can simply use:

```
p "experiment.dat" u 1:(-$2)
```

at least with Version 5.4 works fine.

You can also only use the initial letter of every command.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what you changed and why.

Comment: just to mention: `using 1:(-$2)` will work for gnuplot 4.4 (March 2010) and also for gnuplot 5.2.8 (Dec 2019). But `using 1:($-2)` will not work for gnuplot <=5.2.8. I cannot test 5.4.