# How to change the proportion of the axis in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have two curves; Curve 1 (x1, y1), Curve 2 (x2, y2) in which the value of x2 is equal z times of the value of x1 (e.g., x2 = 1.5 * x1); y axis value is not change. I would like to plot two curves in the same proportion of the x axis value, i.e. i want to change the proportion of x2 value to the x1 value in order to same the peaks of two curves above.
I had tried to find a lot of supports in internet but it has not any suitable result.
Many thanks for your helps.

Comment: You can set different ranges for the axes: `set xrange [-10:10]; set x2range [-15:15]; plot f1(x), f2(1.5*x) axes x2y1`. Otherwise I don't fully understand your question :)

Comment: I think to achieve what he wants you should resize the x2 axis *or* rescale the argument of f2, but not both (otherwise you're just undoing the transformation).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i means that i have two curves with the same ranges of x and y. For example, each of curve has 5 peaks but it is not coincide. So i want to multiply a value 1.0724 of x axis with the second curve in order to move these peaks to the same position with the first curve. Not set the ranges of x-y axes.

Comment: @Miguel Yes, you are right.

Comment: Could you please expand you question with a concrete example? I think the `x2` was a bit confusing for me, because gnuplot actually knows an x and an x2 axis. Do you have functions or data? Whats wrong with something like `plot f1(x), f2(1.5*x)`?

Comment: @ Christoph: There are the data, not is the function. With the function, it is ok. Data1(x1i,y1i), data2(x2i,y2i). I want to plot 'data1(x1i,y1i)','data2(1.0724*x2i,y2i).

Comment: This is the result: https://copy.com/ycFqCqkic7Zq. I want to move the blue curve with the value 1.0724 of x axis in order to coincide the peaks of two curve. Please help me again.

Comment: @Miguel, Christoph: Finally, i found the way to do it. This is the result: plot 'data2' u ($1*1.50):2 --> read in first column and then multiplied by 1.50. Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Comment: OK, so you question is a duplicate of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583526/gnuplot-scale-measuering-data