# Plot negative of an array value in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a file whose data looks as follows,

```
ESCALE ; pCOHP file generated by LOBSTER. Energy is shifted such that the Fermi level lies at 0 eV.
         3          1        301  -6.23689e+00   8.81327e+00   3.79655e+00
Average
No.1:O67->Zr40(2.0986491691399038)
No.2:O67->Zr49(2.0986491691399038)
-10.03344   0.00000  -2.82630   0.00000  -2.82968   0.00000  -2.82292
 -9.98328   0.00000  -2.82630   0.00000  -2.82968   0.00000  -2.82292
 -9.93311   0.00000  -2.82630   0.00000  -2.82968   0.00000  -2.82292
 -9.88294   0.00000  -2.82630   0.00000  -2.82968   0.00000  -2.82292
 -9.83278   0.00000  -2.82630   0.00000  -2.82968   0.00000  -2.82292
 -9.78261   0.00000  -2.82630   0.00000  -2.82968   0.00000  -2.82292
 -9.73244   0.00000  -2.82630   0.00000  -2.82968   0.00000  -2.82292
 ...
 ...
```

Now if I need to plot the second column against first column with gnuplot, I just use the command

```
plot "<fileName>" every ::<startLineNo>::<endLineNo> using 1:2 title '<TitleValue>' with lines
```

where  would be 6 in this case. My question is

*How to plot the negative of the second column values against the first column?*

If I try 1:-2 in the previous command, it throws me a warning that says

> ```
> Warning: empty y range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
> ```

If its hard to plot it using gnuplot, I will appreciate answers using other freely available plotting tools

Comment: See this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19583526/2604213

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to an equivalent question. Apologies for the duplicate. You can close the question.