# How to divide Y-axis data

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting my graph with

```
plot FILE skip 1 u (column(myColumn($0))):(Ymin):(0):(Ymax-Ymin) w vectors nohead lw 1 lc 2 dashtype "-" notitle  ,  FILE2  u 1:2:(myColor(column(-1))) w l lw 2.8 lc rgb var notitle
```

I do not know how to divide colum 2 by a constant number 33.35641.

The solution is

```
 plot FILE skip 1 u (column(myColumn($0))):(Ymin):(0):(Ymax-Ymin) w vectors nohead lw 1 lc 2 dashtype "-" notitle  ,  FILE2  u 1:($2/33.35641):(myColor(column(-1))) w l lw 2.8 lc rgb var notitle
```

Comment: But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583526/scale-measurement-data solves the same problem. In your case `($2/33.35641)`.

Comment: I just have updated my question which contains the answer and yes this is what you advised. I forgot to add $ with 2. Thank you.